# Error: Primary geometry of feature 'null' has 1100253 vertices, above the limit of 1000000 vertices

Tags: google-earth-engine, vertices

I'm pretty new to Earth Engine and I'm trying to export several feature collections.
However for one of those this error keeps occurring whenever I try to run the Export process:
Error: Primary geometry of feature 'null' has 1100253 vertices, above the limit of 1000000 vertices.

Is there any way to reduce the vertices of said feature?

Answer (score 1):

Earth Engine Feature objects have a simplify method: [ee.Feature.simplify(maxError, proj)](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eefeaturesimplify).  You can map this method across all features in your feature collection.